# Lambda function working in below python code snippet

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, lambda, expression

Below code replaces matching `symblsDict` dictionary keys with its values in variable `line`.

```
keys1 = ('|'.join(symblsDict.keys()))
robj1 = re.compile(keys1)
result = robj1.sub(lambda m: symblsDict[m.group(0)], line)
```

In this context Lambda function is used to declare the variable `m` and this hold the matching pattern result .I don't understand how the variable`m` has  the  matching pattern result,as we are not assigning any value to the `m`,just declaring in the function?

```
 Content of Dictionary:{'FTP': 'FTP,COND=(0,LE)', 'TOTAL.LIB6': 'TOTAL.TEST.LIB', 'TOTAL.CTRX': 'TOTAL.TEST.CTRX', 'DD1': 'ZZ.VVMSSB', 'JHSOUT': '*', 'SOUT': '*', 'SALEDB': 'TEST12', 'EMAIL': 'EMAIL,COND=(0,LE)'
    Content of keys1: FTP|TOTAL.LIB6|TOTAL.CTRX|DD1|JHSOUT|SOUT|SALEDB|EMAIL
    Content of line: //             SOUT=A,
    Output://             *=A,
```

Comment: `m` is declared in the function signature `lambda m:`.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda function is being passed to the `sub` method of the compiled regex pattern. That method will call the function with a "match" object every time the pattern matches some text.

When the function is called, the argument name `m` gets bound to the match object. The expression after the colon in the `lambda` can use the argument `m` to compute the return value, which `sub` will substitute in to the string.